# ASP.Net Core WebAPI controller, authorize HTTPClient returning 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-apicontroller, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to create a APIcontroller with a HTTPClient that can read from an external API. When I access the API via a link I get the required response however when I try to connect to it from code I get an unauthorised error. I have tried both Bearer token and Basic authorization.

Here is a sample request URL that returns the correct response:
[RequestURLWithAuthorizationHeader](https://---secretkey----@frost.met.no/sources/v0.jsonld?types=SensorSystem&country=NO&fields=name,geometry,id)

Here is the code I have tried.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FrostMetAPIController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly ILogger<FrostMetAPIController> _logger;
  private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
  private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient
  {
      BaseAddress = new Uri("https://frost.met.no/observations/")
  };

  public FrostMetAPIController(ILogger<FrostMetAPIController> logger, IHttpClientFactory 
         httpClientFactory)
  {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
  }

  [HttpGet("values")]
  public async Task<string> GetRates()
  {
     var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
     try
     {                                
        var _CredentialBase64 = "XXX-xxx-XXX-xxx";                                
        var url = "sources=SN68290:0";
        url += "&referencetime=2019-01-01T12:00:00.000Z/2020-06-30T23:59:59Z";
        url += "&elements=wind_speed,%20max(wind_speed%20PT1H)";
        url += "&timeoffsets=PT0H";
        url += "&timeresolutions=PT1H";
        url += "&timeseriesids=0";
        url += "&performancecategories=C";
        url += "&exposurecategories=2&levels=10.0";
        url = url.Replace(" ", "%20");

       _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                           .Accept                           
 .Add(newMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                           
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {_CredentialBase64}");

        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("v0.jsonld?" + url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
                throw;
            }
     }
  }
```

Comment: 404 is Not Found, not Unauthorized. Which one is it? Also, the code posted doesn't compile. Also, you're mixing `httpClient` and `_httpClient` which makes no sense at all.

Comment: It is 401 Unauthorized error. I have corrected the mistake. The code is compiling now and I have updated a line.

Comment: It looks like this `https://xxx-xxx-xx-xx@frost.met.no/sources/v0.jsonld?types=SensorSystem&country=NO&fields=name,geometry,id)` where xxx-xx-xxx is the authorization secret key.
The API is not well documented and so I am trying it myself.

Comment: So, if you know that the URL must look like that, why exactly are you not building that URL in code? You cannot add keys wherever you want, you need to follow what the API expects

Comment: I did build that in the code but still got the same response of 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Don't tell us, show us the code :) No version with headers is going to work if the URL is not correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237835/discussion-between-user2140740-and-camilo-terevinto).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to add the basic authentication token to the request header of the API url and retrieve the required response from the API

```
  var _authenticationToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx-xx-xxxx"));
  _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
             AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _authenticationToken);

  var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("v0.jsonld?"+ url);                
  var payload = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                              

return payload.Result.ToString();
```

Thanks to @camiloterevinto for the help.